# What is the verb form of newsjacking?

Tags: word-request

What is the verb form of newsjacking? Can I say *I'll newsjack on his divorce and make some money*. I can't find this in the dictionary, though. Could anyone give me some suggestion? Thanks.

Comment: I'm a native speaker, and I've never heard the word "newsjack" before.

Comment: Just thinking in terms of grammar, if a word has an *-ing* ending, then you are looking at the gerund or participle of a noun, and the base form of the noun is *usually* whatever is left after you remove *-ing*: stretching -> stretch, yawning -> yawn, etc. So yes, the bare infinitive would just be "newsjack".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"[Newsjacking](https://blog.hubspot.com/marketing/newsjacking-examples)" is when a brand or firm mentions or creates a campaign centred around a major, well-discussed news item.

So for your example to work, "his divorce" would have to be a well-discussed news item. And you would have to be a brand or firm.  You would say "newsjack his divorce" by analogy with "hijack his aeroplane".

Newsjack is a very recent word, and only really has currency among internet advertisers. It isn't in general circulation.  Standard dictionaries don't (yet) include it.